# How to enable Updates button inside the Publish page in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, updates, xbap

I have a XBAP application that I want it to check for updates each time before it runs. But for some reason Install Mode and Settings section and Updates button are disabled there.

By default its set to available online only so I thought it always checks for updates in this state but that's not the case. When I change the published package in inetpub and then run the application again, it still runs the previous, cached one and it doesn't open the updated version until I remove the app from the cache with mage.exe. So I thought that I should do some configuration in Updates section.

I'm open to any kind of suggestions that helps me to figure out how to check for updates for this XBAP application each time right before it runs.

[Here's how it looks line in Publish section:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a6UC.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot? I can compare with my VS installations, it’s been a while since the last time I worked with VS2010

Comment: Yeah sure, I put the link in above.
Actually I managed to make the automatic updates programmatically but I still need to make this app available offline as well in order to also distribute it as a packaged software that can be used offline.